# How do you exit guided access when it freezes?

Tags: iphone, performance

I accidentally entered guided access by clicking the home button on my phone 3 time while I was on the app "Snapchat" and now I can not leave the app. I have tried clicking the home button three times but nothing happened I also tried holding down on the power button on the side of my iphone and then I tried holding down both the home button and side power button but nothing happened. I can use the app snapchat and send people things but that is all.

Answer (score 3):

- A triple-press of the side button should prompt to exit Guided Access using a passcode.
- A double-press of the side button should use Face ID to authenticate exiting Guided Access.
- [Force restart iPhone](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/iph8903c3ee6/ios):

  > Press and quickly release the volume up button, press and quickly release the volume down button, then press and hold the side button. When the Apple logo appears, release the button.